# Capture a picture in Android, and work with it using the ImageAnalyzer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to implement a solution that would be able to capture a picture from the phone's camera, then operate the picture (do something with it) and repeat this process N times, quickly.

I have achieved this using the `imageCapture.takePicture` method, but when trying to implement the same process for N pictures, the `onCaptureSuccess` method is being called every ~500ms (on a solid Samsung device). The process of capturing and saving the picture lasts too long for me. I need it to be quicker than 500ms.

I was looking to implement it using the `imageAnalyzer` class, and used code similar to this:

```
private class CameraAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
        
        @Override
        public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {

            ByteBuffer bb = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] buf = new byte[bb.remaining()];
            bb.get(buf);
            
            //raw - data container
            raw = buf;
            //runnable - operate the picture
            runnable.run();
            image.close();
        }
    }
```

But I am receiving NULL for `buf` and the picture is always empty. `bb.rewind()` did not help as well.

After being advised that the picture is coming in RAW format, and thus need to convert it to a Bitmap, I have done it with this code:

```
            ImageProxy.PlaneProxy[] planes = image.getPlanes();
            ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
            int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
            int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
            int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * image.getWidth();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth()+rowPadding/pixelStride,
                    image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

But while executing the `copyPixelsFromBuffer` I am encountering this issue:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.strujomeri, PID: 24466
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels
```

**How can I get the picture I want in `imageAnalyzer`, and also have it's content
in `byte[]` format to do with it what I want ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `image` format is YUV_420_888 and as your buffer is only one plane (the Luminance(Y) plane ) the buffer is of pixels that are only a single `byte` in size.

`copyPixelsFromBuffer` assumes that the `buffer` is in the same colour space as the bitmap, so as you set the bitmap format to ARGB_8888 then it is looking for 4 bytes per pixel not 1 byte per pixel you are giving it.

I've not used this but this [page](https://heartbeat.comet.ml/image-classification-on-android-with-tensorflow-lite-and-camerax-4f72e8fdca79) has a `ImageProxy.toBitmap` example to convert a YUV to Bitmap via a Jpeg (if you just wanted a Jpeg you could skip the last step)

I've also seen another [method](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/blob/master/translate/starter/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/codelab/translate/util/ImageUtils.kt) not via Jpeg but to directly change the colorspace of YUV to a bitmap.

You can of course change to the only other colour space ImageAnalysis supports of `ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888` which takes longer to be captured because it needs converting and is still not the right format for a Bitmap

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this solved my issue. I am sharing my code from the final implementation here:

https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#32e862vu0jk2qjam2stv9q

Comment: As the `ImageProxy.toBitmap` code referenced solved your issue, please mark my answer as accepted.